# Come posso esprimere "goteras" in italiano?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Oggi che piove tutto il giorno, abbiamo fatto una bella scoperta: nella nostra sala da pranzo c'è una piccola pioggia che viene da una parte del soffitto.  Abbiamo dei vicini che abitano sopra di noi, ma hanno un terrazzo sopra la nostra sala da pranzo.

In spagnolo, questo fenomeno si chiama "goteras" (e in catalano "goteres"), cioè, questa parola si usa per indicare il gocciolamento di acqua proveniente dal soffitto. Direi "tenemos goteras" per affermare che abbiamo questo problema.

Come dovrei esprimerlo in italiano? Forse "infiltrazioni di acqua dal soffitto"? Anche in castigliano si può dire "infiltraciones de agua" ("infiltracions d'aigua" in catalano), ma si tratta di un linguaggio più tecnico. Magari "gocciolamento di acqua dal soffitto" oppure "perdita di acqua dal soffitto"?

Comment: Che bel momento per avere questo problema! Immagino, però, che sia colpa nostra: c'era una macchiolina sul soffitto, quindi avremmo dovuto fare qualcosa prima di arrivare a questa situazione.

Comment: Io userei "infiltrazione" o "gocciolamento" in questo caso, "perdita" mi fa pensare che il problema sia dovuto a una tubatura, e se ho capito bene non è questo il caso, se sopra il punto dove gocciola c'è un terrazzo.

Comment: Benissimo, @RiccardoDeContardi: potresti scriverlo come risposta? Sì, il problema è dovuto (credo) all'acqua piovana che s'infiltra dal terrazzo dei vicini di sopra.

Comment: Sala *da* pranzo.

Comment: Hai ragione, @egreg: corretto. Grazie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Io userei il termine *"infiltrazione di acqua dal soffitto"* o *"gocciolamento di acqua dal soffitto"* in questo caso - vanno entrambi bene; *"perdita di acqua dal soffitto"* mi fa pensare che il problema sia dovuto ad una tubatura danneggiata, e se ho capito bene non è questo il caso, se sopra il punto dove gocciola c'è un terrazzo.

Come scritto da @Charo nel suo commento, la causa del problema potrebbe essere un ristagno di acqua piovana.

Nota: secondo me (parere personale) si potrebbe omettere *di acqua* ... di solito è implicito che sia una infiltrazione di acqua e non di altro liquido. Invece, è meglio sempre specificare *dal soffitto* in modo che sia chiaro dove si sta producendo il danno dell'infiltrazione.

Comment: Grazie, @Riccardo. Tuttavia, semplicemente "infiltrazioni" o "gocciolamento"? O dovrei aggiungere "di acqua"? E dovrei specificare anche "dal soffitto"? Perché un'infiltrazione potrebbe anche essere in un muro, vero? Invece, quando in castigliano si dice "goteras" è sempre qualcosa che viene dal soffitto (ecco un [esempio](https://www.cantitec.es/problema-de-goteras-como-prevenirlo/)).

Comment: Beh di solito non sono di aranciata :) Scherzi a parte, ho semplicemente evitato di ripetere l'intera frase "... di acqua dal soffitto", visto che di quello si parlava -  adesso modifico la risposta per maggior dettaglio. Certo, una infiltrazione può anche essere dal muro.

Comment: E, per di più, non sembra voler smettere di piovere! :(